# How declare DbSet<dynamic>?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to declare DbSet in my Databases Context class.
Because I don't which class (Entity Framwork Class) user calls.
That's why I want to declare the DbSet with dynamic.

Comment: What have you tried? What is your specific use case? I think it's better to have everything explicitly defined in the context, and then do the dynamic stuff at a different level.

Comment: I resolved my issue by returning the JSON value in simple string entity class.
Same string converted into object in Angular and my issue got resolved by this way.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to have everything explicitly defined in your context. There's a lot of functionality baked into that property declaration, not the least of which is the design-time benefit of having types.

There are many techniques for dynamic querying, but I'll post one that I've used in the past for dynamically querying lookup tables.

```
public List<LookupItemDTO> LoadItems(int lookupId)
{
    //nothing special here, just map the lookup id to a name
    var lookupRepo = new LookupRepository<LookupDefinition>(uow);
    var lookup = lookupRepo.Find(id);

    //map the lookup's name from the table to a type. This is important DO NOT ACCEPT A TABLE NAME FROM THE USER.
    var targetType = Type.GetType("MyApp.DomainClasses.Lookup." + lookup.Name + ",MyApp.DomainClasses");
    // this is an optional extra step but it allows us to instantiate an instance of our repository to ensure that business rules are enforced
    var lookupType = typeof(LookupRepository<>).MakeGenericType(targetType);
    dynamic LookupTable = Activator.CreateInstance(lookupType);
    //just some pattern nonsense to wire up the unit of work
    LookupTable.SetupUOW(uow);

    //make sure to cast it into something you can work with ASAP
    var data = ((IQueryable<LookupTableBase>)LookupTable.All).OrderByDescending(l => l.IsVisible).ThenBy(l => l.SortOrder);

    var list = from li in data
               select new LookupItemDTO
               {
                   Id = li.Id,
                   Description = li.Description,
                   Display = li.Display,
                   SortOrder = li.SortOrder,
                   IsVisible = li.IsVisible
               };

    return list.ToList();
}
```

The key here is that you *can* dynamically query tables, but it's better to do it at a higher level. Also, have some kind of indirection between you and your user's input. Let them select a table from a list, use the ID from that table to look up the name. My solution here is the have a lookup table definition table. Any dynamic queries start there *first* and then values from that definition table are used to build the necessary types.